# How can i resolve problems with the EventListener?

Tags: java, android, listener, event-listener, vungle-ads

My Code:

```
final VunglePub vunglePub = VunglePub.getInstance();
```

[...]

```
final AdConfig globalAdConfig = vunglePub.getGlobalAdConfig();
```

[...]

```
final VungleAdEventListener vungleListener = new VungleAdEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAdEnd(String placementReferenceId, boolean wasSuccessfulView, boolean wasCallToActionClicked) {
        Toast.makeText(Start.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdStart(String placemetReferenceId) {
        Toast.makeText(Start.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onUnableToPlayAd(String placementReferenceId, String reason) {
        Toast.makeText(Start.this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdAvailabilityUpdate(String placementReferenceId, boolean isAdAvailable) {
        Toast.makeText(Start.this, "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

[...]

onCreate:

```
// initialize Publisher SDK with app id, placement reference id list and init callback handler
    vunglePub.init(this, "XXXXX", new String[] { "PLACEMEXXXXXX" }, new VungleInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e){
        }
    });


    vunglePub.clearAndSetEventListeners(vungleListener);
    globalAdConfig.setSoundEnabled(false);
    globalAdConfig.setOrientation(Orientation.autoRotate);
    vunglePub.playAd("PLACEMEXXXXX", globalAdConfig);
```

My App shows a vungle-ad, but I get not the Toasts "1" by onAdEnd from the vungleListener. I cant find my mistake

Answer (score 0):

I found this explanation at this [link](https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463100-Advanced-Settings-Vungle-Android-SDK-v-1-0-v-4-1)

- The method `onAdEnd` is called when the user leaves the ad and control is returned to your application.
- If `wasSuccessfulView` is `true`, the user watched the ad and should be rewarded (if this was a rewarded ad).
- If `wasCallToActionClicked` is `true`, the user clicked the call to action button in the ad.

So, you must click on the Ad and return to your application to get the toast "1".

Comment: @Override
        public void onAdEnd(String placementReferenceId, boolean wasSuccessfulView, boolean wasCallToActionClicked) {
            if(wasSuccessfulView) Toast.makeText(Start.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

Comment: Gives me no toast :-(

Comment: And I get no Toasts. No "1", no "2", no "3" and no "4" Toast :-(

Comment: Try calling `vunglePub.clearAndSetEventListeners(vungleListener);`before calling init command.